# When using the magnifier, it is displayed incorrectly

Tags: ios, iphone

[Code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok9mA.png)

Here is my code
In the second picture, the magnifier works correctly
And when I want to make a magnifying glass exactly in place by pressing, there is first a normal press, and then a sharp increase. After that, the magnifier always remains the same.
[Magnify with - 80 on Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncwY2.png)

[Magnify with Y = point.y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VKkR.png)

Comment: Please paste your code into your question instead of linking to a picture of it. People will often want to be able to copy the code and try it out themselves, or just copy a portion into their answers for clarity.

Comment: This is my first question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a kind of feedback issue... the magnifier is magnifying an area occupied by the magnifier, so the black pixels in the center of that spot are enlarged, adding more black pixels to that area and causing the magnifier to be redrawn with more black, and so on, until the entire magnifier is filled.

And whether that's the actual cause or not, I think it's always best to offset the magnifier some so that you can actually see it. If you don't, the magnifier will be under your finger, so there's not much point in showing it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you help me ? I need it to be exactly in the center and have a zoom with UIPinchGestureRecognizer. How can this be done?

Comment: @ArtemG Start by making sure that you're not drawing the magnifier in the same context that it's magnifying.